# Delphi Xe3 TidIRC Unicode Support

Tags: delphi, unicode, irc

Is it possible to get there unicode support?

If i send message to a channel like :

```
  IRC.Say('#lobby' ,Edit2.Text);
```

ä,ü,ß

The output is

```
?,?,?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobal;

IdIRC1.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyUTF8Encoding;
```